# Why can't mail clients verify an email was sent from the user and server it claims to be from?

Tags: email, phishing, spoofing, email-spoofing

## Background

When I explain to my clients the security issues around email spoofing, I often explain that emails are like regular mail. Anyone can write **Jon Doe** on the return address, but that doesn't necessarily mean that **Jon Doe** sent it.

## Potential Solution?

Why can't an email server be setup to receive the following fields over a TLS session:

`domain`
`sender`
`hash of email`

And return *True* if an email was sent that fits those values.

After every email the client receives, it can reach out to that email server with those values. If the client gets a return of *False*, just drop the email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, its not that easy.

Almost all SMTP servers are configured to prioritise the delivery of emails. This makes for example encryption between servers opportunistic today. Another problem is, how can you know for certain that a specific mail server is the only one allowed to send emails for a specific domain? Also a email almost always pass through many servers before reaching its destination. This is only a few of the problems we are facing.

**Possible solutions**

There are several solutions to this problem that are widely used at the moment. But I think the biggest problems are adoption and ease of configuration.

Here is a few:

1. DKIM and DMARC - the server signs sent emails with a asymmetric key, where the public key is published in DNS, this way the receiving server can verify the authenticity of that email.
2. SPF - You add DNS records that tell what servers are allowed to send emails for a specific domain. This way (if the receiving end honours it) emails from a domain will only be accepted from a defined set of servers.
3. S/MIME - the USER signs the email with a x509-certificate from a trusted CA, this way you can be reasonably sure that the email was sent from the person you think it was.
4. PGP signing of emails

The problem I guess is that solution 1-2 is hard to setup for administrators (and voluntary) and solution 3-4 is even harder to setup for the user.

Your solution would require new protocols implemented in the email client and would take a very long time to see widespread adoption.

Comment: Also see SPF: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework

Comment: Oops, totally forgot. Will add it.

Comment: For example google require SPF records (at least for IPv6). So, if you dont use it there is a big risk that gmail will drop them.

Comment: @Peter yea, you're right, there would have to be some sort conversation between the server that is responsible for the domain and the server that sent the actual email.

Comment: DKIM signatures can get broken by relays, especially mailing lists. See [Authenticated Received Chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_Received_Chain) (ARC) for an attempt at resolving that (which requires trust).